# About Debugging program using ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

ROS is based on process communication. Can I do things in a single process?
Sometime I just want some lightweight operations and resorting to process is too costly.
Also, have multiple thread is inconvenient for me to use debug tools and IDE such as qtCreator.

I'm new to ROS, sorry for the possibly silly question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220218/about-debugging-program-using-ros/) by [DamnItROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/24967/damnitros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS communications primitives work for both interprocess as well as intraprocess. See the [publish subscribe overview](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) for details on how to optimized using `boost::shared_ptr`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DamnItROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/24967/damnitros/) on 2015-11-02**:
That's cool. So it's automatically managed by ROS. Thanks!